# Is there an existing I18N translation for booleans?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

I need to display "Yes" or "No" in various languages based on whether a expression is true or false. Currently I am doing it like this:

#### fr.yml:

```
fr:
  "yes": Oui
  "no": Non
```

#### a helper method:

```
def t_boolean(expression)
  (expression) ? t("yes") : t("no")
end
```

#### erb:

```
Valid: <%= t_boolean(something.is_valid?) %>
```

Is there some better way to do this?

Does Rails already have translations for true/false like this?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

After reading [this](http://groups.google.com/group/rails-i18n/browse_thread/thread/68bf84775635286a), I got inspired and figured out this solution:

#### fr.yml

```
fr:
  "true": Oui
  "false": Non
```

erb:

```
Valid: <%= t something.is_valid?.to_s %>
```

**Update**

For english, if you want to use `yes` and `no` as values, be sure to quote them:

#### en.yml

```
en:
  "true": "yes"
  "false": "no"
```

Comment: Here's a shorter code for boolean translations:


`Valid: <%= t( something.is_valid?.present?.to_s ) %>`

Comment: Also with italian you have to use "true":"si" and "false":"no" with double quotes.

Answer (score 10):

Just as Zabba says works fine, but if you are trying to translate true-false into yes-no, quote both sides, else you'll get true translated into true (TrueClass) again.

```
en:
  "true": "yes"
  "false": "no"
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try overriding I18n's default [`translate` method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/translation_helper.rb#L46-55), delegating to the default method to do the actual translation. Use this code in an initializer:

```
module I18n
  class << self
    alias :__translate :translate #  move the current self.translate() to self.__translate()
    def translate(key, options = {})
      if key.class == TrueClass || key.class == FalseClass
        return key ? self.__translate("yes", options) : self.__translate("no", options)
      else
        return self.__translate(key, options)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure that will come in handy sometime! But for now, I discovered a simple solution (added as answer)

Answer (score 1):

```
# Inside initializer
module I18n
  class << self
    alias :__translate :translate #  move the current self.translate() to self.__translate()
     alias :t :translate
     def translate(key, options = {})
       if key.class == TrueClass || key.class == FalseClass
         return key ? self.__translate("boolean.true", options) : self.__translate("boolean.false", options)
       else
         return self.__translate(key, options)
       end
     end
  end
end

# Inside locale
boolean:
  :true: 'Yes'
  :false: 'No'

# Calling translate
I18n.translate(is_this_my_boolean_column)
```

Working with Rails 3.2.2 :)

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the **translate** method had been aliased in [I18n](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/blob/master/lib/i18n.rb).

When you alias a method you are actually creating a new copy of it so only redefining the **translate** method will not work when calls to the **t** method occurs.
In order to make the above code to work you could, for example, alias the **t** method, too.

```
module I18n
  class << self
    alias :__translate :translate #  move the current self.translate() to self.__translate()
    alias :t : translate # move the current self.t() to self.translate()
    def translate(key, options = {})
      if key.class == TrueClass || key.class == FalseClass
        return key ? self.__translate("yes", options) : self.__translate("no", options)
      else
        return self.__translate(key, options)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It's not working for me with rails 3.2, any idea? I put this code in an initializer

Comment: Besides redefining t and transalate methods you should do "fr:
  "yes": Oui
  "no": Non

Comment: I still get yes/no, i am working with activeadmin, it's maybe the problem. But i think it's independent.

Answer (score 0):

Other solution I prefer:

```
# Create a helper
def yes_no(bool_value)
  if bool_value
    t(:yes_word)
  else
    t(:no_word)
  end
end

# Add the translations, important that you use " around yes or no.
yes_word: "No"
no_word: "Yes"

# In your views, in my case in slim:
span= yes_no myvalue
# Or ERB
<%= yes_no(myvalue) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

**For any boolean translation**

I just love that boolean pluralization hack

```
# some_view.html.erb
t(:are_you_ok?, count: (user.is_ok? ? 0 : 1)  ).html_safe
```

Translations

```
# locales/en.yml
en:
  are_you_ok?:
    zero: "You are <strong>NOT</strong> ok ! Do something !"
    one: "You are doing fine"
```

You don't even need quotes actually ^^.